# Can I upload full playthroughs onto YouTube?

Tags: youtube

Is it OK to post long gameplay (playthroughs) captured videos on YouTube, of games such as: Outlast, Outlast 2, WoW, Among Us, Cattails, Dead Space, etc.

Or are these videos going to be removed from YouTube and the channel penalized?

Or are some games/companies OK with people posting playthroughs, while other games/companies are actively against it? And if so, which ones are OK with it?

Comment: I hope you don't plan on doing a 100% playthrough of WoW...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

YouTube, in short, will not penalize you for uploading gameplay videos, except for a few exceptions:

1. **The video or description violates one of YouTube's Terms of Service**, which you are required to follow *(rules on abuse, hate speech, etc).*
2. **You have copyrighted music playing.** The YouTube AI will automatically copyright claim your video if it has music playing in the background that is protected by copyright laws. *(examples include GTA radio or cutscene music)*
3. **You are openly plagiarizing another video.** It's pretty self-explanatory, just don't steal other people's stuff.

But other than those basic rules, you should be free to post nearly any game you want on YouTube.

Comment: Note on #2; this can be triggered from any in-game music that was not made specifically for the game (and even then)... So if recording something like GTA; best to turn off the radio, and/or turn off music in the game's options (cutscenes with music may still be problematic)

Comment: "YouTube, in short, will not penalize you for uploading gameplay videos" Unless you count being demoted to "Youtube Gaming" on the Trending Tab as a penalty. It's possible that you might get demoted by the algorithm in general, for that matter.

Comment: Rule #2 is utterly detrimental to enjoying a video of THPS2 :-(

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yup, it stinks, but we can’t change it so might as well live with it. :/

Comment: note #3 can also happen on accident, remember when guinness accidentally copyrighted thousands of videos of speedruns? yeah that happens sometimes

Comment: @OKprogrammer *sad Superman noises* :'-/

Comment: A major problem with YouTube's DMCA policy is that it fails to provide any means by which posters can claim good-faith belief that the conduct represented fair use, and give copyright claimants the choice to either accept the claim (material is taken down without a strike) or contest it (giving the poster the right to sue the claimant for tortuous interference if a jury finds that the use was fair).  The DMCA grants venues considerable latitude with regard to what policies they implement for habitual offenders, and while a three-strikes policy would be appropriate for...

Comment: ...some kinds of blatant infringement, it would be inappropriate in cases where claimants would be unwilling to accept liability for tortuous interference if they shut down a channel because of copyright claims which are found to have been illegitimate.

Comment: @supercat "giving the poster the right to sue the claimant for tortuous interference if a jury finds that the use was fair" is quite some wishful thinking. [As of May 2019, more than 500 hours of video were uploaded to YouTube every minute.](https://www.statista.com/statistics/259477/hours-of-video-uploaded-to-youtube-every-minute/) I don't think that YouTube would ever invest resources into such a thing. The industry has moved to an "ask for permission" policy rather than "beg for forgiveness"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: The resources involved would essentially be a form of counter-notification which would leave the work taken down, but would only result in a copyright strike if the claimant, after reviewing it, notified YouTube that the work could not have been plausibly posted in reasonable good faith.  Basically, the system should be set up to facilitate what should be the most common case--the "no harm no foul" scenario where someone with no desire to use material in ways the rights-holder would disapprove, uses it n ways that were not intended to be objectionable, but were.

Answer (score 5):

OKprogrammer describes the current status quo: most companies are okay with playthroughs being posted online. However, I do want to point out that this does fall into a legal gray area that has not to my knowledge been tested in court yet. Game companies may make copyright claims over playthroughs posted online, and have done so in the past:

- [Campo Santo filed a copyright claim against PewDiePie](https://www.polygon.com/2017/9/14/16309430/pewdiepie-campo-santo-strike) and had a YouTube video taken down where he played their game *Firewatch*.
- Nintendo has at some points in the past [claimed ad revenue](https://www.ign.com/articles/2013/05/16/nintendo-enforces-copyright-on-youtube-lets-plays) on playthrough videos of their games, though they do [currently allow players to monetize videos of their gameplay](https://www.nintendo.co.jp/networkservice_guideline/en/index.html).

Odds are that you will be fine, as most studios recognize the promotional value of Let's Plays, and would not want to face a backlash from gamers for being seen as (ab)using copyright. I'm not aware of any studios that actively prohibit playthroughs. I just want to point out that the risk, while very low, is not zero.

Further reading:

- [Let's Play: Copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Play#Copyright) on Wikipedia
- [Are Let’s Play videos legal?](https://odinlaw.com/are-lets-play-videos-legal/) from Odin Law
- [Table of explicitly-"Let's Play"-friendly developers](https://letsplaylist.fandom.com/wiki/%22Let%27s_Play%22-friendly_developers_Wiki)

Comment: Basically its that Video game companies would be in their right to take down videos of their games, and some did try. But it is, for now, a PR suicide to do so. The only ones that really tried hard was Nintendo, the company that can't seem to have bad press and is eternally loved by gamers, and even them had to back down following the backlash.

Comment: @Fred31 Thank you for providing this angle. The question was originally prompted because a playthrough video apparently disappeared from a friend's channel, and it wasn't clear whether it had been taken down, or what.